# Changing values inside a cell from a table view controller through the app delegate

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, appdelegate

I'm working on an project which uses geofences and stores certain data when these geofences are entered and exited, and want to present this data within a table.

I'm using the didEnterRegion and didExitRegion functions in my app delegate and want to be able to modify the cells from these functions but I'm not quite sure how to reference the cells in my table view from the app delegate.

I'm currently using static cells and making IBOutlet connections in the class related to the table view controller if I want to change the data in the referenced cell but am unsure how to use this method for making changes from the app delegate.

I'm happy to completely change this whole method for a better one, as this isn't currently working for me, but would rather if there was a way of doing this which is related to what I've currently done (albeit not much, but I understand this method).

Thanks!

Comment: can you provide code or more specific info of your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Your table view cell must change when the geofences are entered and exited.

So your table view cell needs to change depending on some other class.

1. Create a protocol the methods with methods that would be invoked by the table view controller.

Example:

```
protocol GeoFenceDelegate {
    didEnter() -> Bool
    didExit() -> Bool
}
```

2. Create a class `GeoLocation` to handle all Geo fencing.
3. Let `GeoLocation` conform to `GeoFenceDelegate`
4. Your table view controller should have a `weak` reference to `GeoFenceDelegate` pointing to `GeoLocation`
5. In your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` invoke the methods of `GeoFence` and update your cell accordingly.
6. Also when ever the geolocation has changed, you can post notifications on the main thread
7. The table view controller can observe these notifications and reload the cells in the table